# @HTML.DisplayFor is displaying unwanted markup

Tags: c#, .net, model

I am new to Entity Framework. When I am trying to display using @HTML.DisplayFor. It is displaying extra markup which is resulting as blank in HTML page.

Example: "Test Text" is displayed as `<Test> <td> </Text>`
Sample Code Looks As Below.

Model

```
public class ThirdParty
{

    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Options { get; set; }
    public List<string> InputVariables { get; set; }
}

public class ValidationMessage
{

    public string IsRequired { get; set; }
    public List<string> InputVariables { get; set; }
}
  public class LicenseBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<BaseModule> BaseModules { get; set; }
        public List<ThirdParty> ThirdParty { get; set; }
        public List<string> InputVariables { get; set; }
        public List<ValidationMessage> ValidationMessages { get; set; }
        public List<JPT> JPTProducts { get; set; }
    }
public class BaseModule
{

    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{

    public LicenseBase License { get; set; }
    public List<LicenseBase> SubLicenses {get;set;}        

}
```

The problem occurred when I tried to display BaseModule in index.chtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor()` will render a markup template based on the properties type which explains where your unwanted markup is coming from.

From MSDN:

> Returns HTML markup for each property in the object that is represented by the Expression expression.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

You probably want to use something like [@Html.Raw()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! But, @HTML.Raw() is returning Something like <Test> </Text>.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had extra "<" before the function which was generating unwanted markup (or getting interpreted as markup by browser)